# SCSS - Make div1 disappear on hover of div2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I want a div to disappear on hover over a different div, purely with CSS.
So I have two divs

```
<div class="" id="target">I will disappear</div>
<div class="hover_box">Hover me</div>
```

and my SCSS:

```
#target {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.hover_box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

    &:hover #target{
      display: none !important;
      /* background-color: green !important; */
    }
}
```

However, it does not work. See here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ubLLga3q/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your HTML mark up. You are doing a hover and saying #target disappear. You can only use this method if you call a sibling/child. Right now #target is not a child from .hover_box.

```
<div class="box">
  Hover me
   <div class="hover_box">

  </div>
</div>

.box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.hover_box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box:hover .hover_box {
  display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ubLLga3q/6/